# select string from database in PHP

Tags: php

I have a web page that you can search a database. The user can search on 5 different fields and the page sends the inputs through via post. Some of the fields can be null when the hit search. is there a nice select statement I can use rather than a whole lot of if statements.

```
$Country = $_POST['Country'];
$Gender = $_POST['Gender'];
$lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
$firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
$sport = $_POST['sport'];   

//selects sport and country
    if  (($lastName == null) && ($firstName == null) && ($Gender == null))
    {
    $selectString = "SELECT * FROM tblCountry JOIN tblAthletes ON          (tblAthletes.countryCode = tblCountry.countryCode ) WHERE (name = '$Country') AND (sport ='$sport') ";
    }


  //selects country and gender and sport
  if (($lastName == null) && ($firstName == null))
    {

        $selectString = "SELECT * FROM tblCountry JOIN tblAthletes ON (tblAthletes.countryCode = tblCountry.countryCode ) WHERE (name = '$Country') AND (gender ='$Gender') AND (sport = '$sport')";
    }


    //selects country and last and first name
    else if ($Gender == null)
    {
        $selectString = "SELECT * FROM tblCountry JOIN tblAthletes ON (tblAthletes.countryCode = tblCountry.countryCode ) WHERE (name = '$Country') AND (firstName LIKE '%$firstName%') AND (lastName LIKE '%$lastName%') AND (sport = '$sport') ";
    }

    //selects sport, gender, last name and country 
    else if  ($firstName == null)
    {
    $selectString = "SELECT * FROM tblCountry JOIN tblAthletes ON (tblAthletes.countryCode = tblCountry.countryCode ) WHERE (name = '$Country') AND (sport ='$sport') AND (gender ='$Gender') AND (lastName LIKE '%$lastName%') ";
    }

    //selects sport, gender, first name and country 
    else if  ($lastName == null)
    {
    $selectString = "SELECT * FROM tblCountry JOIN tblAthletes ON (tblAthletes.countryCode = tblCountry.countryCode ) WHERE (name = '$Country') AND (sport ='$sport') AND (gender ='$Gender') AND (firstName LIKE '%$firstName%') ";
    }

    //selects just country
 if (($Gender == null) && ($lastName == null) && ($firstName == null) && ($sport == null))
    {
        $selectString = "SELECT * FROM tblCountry JOIN tblAthletes ON (tblAthletes.countryCode = tblCountry.countryCode ) WHERE  (name ='$Country') ";
    }


         //selects just sport
     else if (($lastName == null) && ($firstName == null) && ($Gender == null) && ($Country == 'country'))
    {
        $selectString = "SELECT * FROM tblCountry JOIN tblAthletes ON (tblAthletes.countryCode = tblCountry.countryCode ) WHERE (sport = '$sport') ORDER BY sport ";
    }

         //selects just last name
     else if (($sport == null) && ($firstName == null) && ($Gender == null) && ($Country == 'country'))
    {
        $selectString = "SELECT * FROM tblCountry JOIN tblAthletes ON (tblAthletes.countryCode = tblCountry.countryCode ) WHERE (lastName = '$lastName') ORDER BY sport ";
    }

    //selects gender and last name
    else if (($Country == 'country') && ($firstName == null))
    {
        $selectString = "SELECT * FROM tblCountry JOIN tblAthletes ON (tblAthletes.countryCode = tblCountry.countryCode ) WHERE (lastName LIKE '%$lastName%') AND (gender LIKE '%$Gender%') AND (sport = '$sport') ";

    }


    //selects gender and first name
    else if (($Country == 'country') && ($lastName == null))
    {
        $selectString = "SELECT * FROM tblCountry JOIN tblAthletes ON (tblAthletes.countryCode = tblCountry.countryCode ) WHERE (firstName LIKE '%$firstName%') AND (gender = '$Gender') AND (sport = '$sport')  ";

    }


    //selects country, sport and first name
    else if (($Gender == null) && ($lastName == null))
    {
        $selectString = "SELECT * FROM tblCountry JOIN tblAthletes ON (tblAthletes.countryCode = tblCountry.countryCode ) WHERE (firstName LIKE '%$firstName%') AND (sport = '$sport') AND (name = '$Country') ";

    }


    //selects last name, sport and first name
    else if (($Gender == null) && ($Country == 'country'))
    {
        $selectString = "SELECT * FROM tblCountry JOIN tblAthletes ON (tblAthletes.countryCode = tblCountry.countryCode ) WHERE (firstName LIKE '%$firstName%') AND (sport = '$sport') AND (lastName LIKE '%$lastName%') ";

    }
    // selects sport and gender
    else if (($Country == null) && ($lastName == null) && ($firstName == null)) 
    {
        $selectString = "SELECT * FROM tblCountry JOIN tblAthletes ON (tblAthletes.countryCode = tblCountry.countryCode ) WHERE (gender = '%Gender%') AND (sport = '$sport') ";
    }

    // selects gender
    else if (($Country == null) && ($lastName == null) && ($firstName == null) && ($sport == null ) ) 
    {
        $selectString = "SELECT * FROM tblCountry JOIN tblAthletes ON (tblAthletes.countryCode = tblCountry.countryCode ) WHERE (gender = '%Gender%')  ";
    }

    // selects country and last name 
    else if (($Gender == null) && ($firstName == null ) && ($sport == null))
    {
        $selectString = "SELECT * FROM tblCountry JOIN tblAthletes ON (tblAthletes.countryCode = tblCountry.countryCode ) WHERE  (name = '$Country') AND (lastName LIKE '%$lastName%') ";
    }


    // selects country and first name 
else  if (($Gender == null) && ($lastName == null ) && ($sport == null))
    {
        $selectString = "SELECT * FROM tblCountry JOIN tblAthletes ON (tblAthletes.countryCode = tblCountry.countryCode ) WHERE  (name = '$Country') AND (firstName LIKE '%$firstName%') ";
    }


        // selects all
    else if (($Gender == null) && ($firstName == null ) && ($sport == null) && ($lastName == null) && ($Country == 'country') )
    {
        $selectString = "SELECT * FROM tblCountry JOIN tblAthletes ON (tblAthletes.countryCode = tblCountry.countryCode )";
    }
    // selects if all feilds full
    else 
    {
        $selectString = "SELECT * FROM tblCountry JOIN tblAthletes ON (tblAthletes.countryCode = tblCountry.countryCode ) WHERE (name = '$Country') AND (gender ='$Gender') AND (lastName LIKE '%$lastName%') AND (firstName LIKE '%$firstName%') ORDER BY lastName ";
    }

    $result = mysql_query($selectString);


    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
    echo"<tr>";
        foreach($row as $index=>$value)
        {
            if(($index == 'flagImage')||($index == 'atheleteImage'))
            {
                //Gets images
                echo"<td><img title='competitor' alt='' src='images/$value' width='80' height='80'/></td>";
            }
         else
            {
                echo("<td>$value</td>");
            }
        }
    echo"</tr>";
    }
    echo"</table>";
    echo"</div>";

}
```

Comment: Do you have any solution already or just want us to do your work?

Comment: I have a whole lot of if statements

Comment: so show it so we could help you to improve it, not just do your work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    your_table_here
WHERE
        (('' = :country) OR country = :country)
    AND (('' = :gender) OR gender = :gender)
    AND (('' = :lastName) OR lastName = :lastName)
    AND (('' = :firstName) OR firstName = :firstName)
    AND (('' = :sport) OR sport = :sport)
;
```

You can adapt this to check for NULL values instead of empty strings, using IS_NULL(:country) etc. instead of '' = :country.

And, of course: [Remeber to sanitize your database inputs.](http://xkcd.com/327/)

**EDIT:**
With IS NULL:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    your_table_here
WHERE
        (IS NULL(:country) OR country = :country)
    AND (IS NULL(:gender) OR gender = :gender)
    AND (IS NULL(:lastName) OR lastName = :lastName)
    AND (IS NULL(:firstName) OR firstName = :firstName)
    AND (IS NULL(:sport) OR sport = :sport)
```

;

Comment: I am having problems with IS_NULL could you expand a little for me please?

Answer (score 0):

Yup.

```
SELECT `Country`, `Gender`, `lastName`, `firstName`, `sport` FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE Country='$country'...etc
```

Make sure you're using `mysqli` or `PDO`.  The legacy `mysql` functions have major security holes.